# Node MySQL Connection Pool - wait for database to start

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

How do I check if a MySQL database is ready for some queries from a Node MySQL Connection Pool?

I have a Docker environment consisting of thee containers:

- container 1: web server
- container 2: api
- container 3: database

The database container runs a MySQL database. The api container connects to that database. All three containers are started at the same time. The web server container is up after 0,5s. The api container is up after 2s. The database server is up after 20s.

Currently, the api tries to access the tables of the database before the database is up and running. This leads to errors like *connection refused*. The following code segment always ends up with the message "Error querying database!" when the MySQL database is not yet up:

```
const sql: string = 'SELECT * FROM sometable;';
MySQL.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    acquireTimeout: 30000,
    waitForConnections: true,
    database: 'mydatabase',
    host: 'localhost',
    multipleStatements: true,
    password: 'mypassword',
    user: 'root',
}).query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (result) {
        console.log('Successfully queried database.');
    } else {
        console.log('Error querying database!');
    }
});
```

Versions in use:

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10
Node: v13.6.0
MySQL (Node API): "@types/mysql": "2.15.8" and "mysql": "2.17.1"
MySQL (Docker Database): mysql:5.7.28
TypeScript: 3.7.4
```

I would like to check (and wait) the database readiness out of the api, possibly using the Connection Pool I use for queries. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Retry to connect with `setTimeout()`:

(answer in Javascript rather than typescript)

```
'use strict';

const dbpool = require('mysql').createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    acquireTimeout: 30000,
    waitForConnections: true,
    database: 'mydatabase',
    host: 'localhost',
    multipleStatements: true,
    password: 'mypassword',
    user: 'root',
});

const sql = 'SELECT * FROM sometable;';

const attemptConnection = () =>
  dbpool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error connecting. retrying in 1 sec');
    setTimeout(attemptConnection, 1000);
  } else {
    connection.query(sql, (errQuery, results) => {
      connection.release();
      if (errQuery) {
        console.log('Error querying database!');
      } else {
        console.log('Successfully queried database.');
      }
    });
  }
});

attemptConnection();
```

Here is my test run:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop; node test.js & sudo service mysql start
[1] 24737
error connecting. retrying in 1 sec
error connecting. retrying in 1 sec
$ Successfully queried database.
```

FYI, The program never ends because it needs `dbpool.end()`;

Comment: IMO it should be obligatory to provide a statement when placing a downvote. @StackOverflow: Please do that! ;)
As for your code, it helped! And it actually is so simple! Thanks for your help niry.

Comment: why don't you simply finish the function `attemptConnection` with `})());`, i.e., you self invoke it: https://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: I got it, the callback in `setTimeout` can't be a self-invoked function, ignore hence my last comment

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira you could do `let attemptConnection; (attemptConnection = () => '...')()` but you can't do it with `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Your API should try to connect to the database with a timeout and a certain threshold of connection attempts. However, there are readily available solutions for this scenario.

Try using [wait-for-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-for-mysql) module.

> ```
> waitForMy = require 'wait-for-mysql'
> config =
>   username: user
>   password: pass
>   quiet: true
>   query: 'SELECT 1'
>
> waitForMy.wait(config)
> ```

Comment: You have a typo in `wait-form-mysql` link. it should be `wait-for-mysql`. If you look at the source code of it, it does what I've suggested, right here: `setTimeout testConnection, connectDelay`

Comment: @niry We should always use existing libraries without trying tto reinvent the wheel. Thanks for the tip of the typo.

Comment: Ho did you get all the way to "reinventing the wheel"? It is merely `setTimeout()` and wrapping in a function.

Comment: Why should you write any code when there is a library which just does that?

Comment: I'm not against using libraries, and your solution might work perfectly fine. Here are example reasons to not use a library: #1. You want to learn. #2. Not maintained libraries tend to cause issues (FYI, Latest commit was on Sep 29, 2015) #3. Adding a library when the solution is so simple isn't really saving anything, in fact, it might cost you more.

Comment: #1 - Learn it separately and use an existing library in production. #3 - Its saves your time. Look at the number - 603 weekly downloads

Comment: #1 - "Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for anyone that codes to learn...". #3 - there is absolutely no correlation between weekly downloads and time saved or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a variation but with no need to mysql pooling. I'm using this on my server and it does work:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql')
var db // global, to use later to db.query
var dbInfo = {
  host     : 'example.org',
  database : 'some_database',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
}

function connectToDb(callback) {
  const attemptConnection = () => {
    console.log('Attempting to connect to db')
    dbInfo.connectTimeout = 2000 // same as setTimeout to avoid server overload 
    db = mysql.createConnection(dbInfo)
    db.connect(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to database, try again in 1 sec...')
        db.destroy() // end immediately failed connection before creating new one
        setTimeout(attemptConnection, 2000)
      } else {
        callback()
      }
    })
  }
  attemptConnection()
}

// now you simply call it with normal callback
connectToDb( () => {
  console.log('Connection successfully')
  // do some queries
  db.query(..)
})
```